# How to get the exe file in the project folder using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the `setup.py` of my project. I am trying to create an exe runnable for my project.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='Call',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        call=call.scripts.call:generate_trivia
    ''',
)
```

Whenever I ran the command `python setup.py install` I have seen that the exe is getting created in my Python folder under the sub-folder `Scripts`
I am using `Windows 10`. Hence, kindly guide me what I can do to have the exe in the same folder where my setup.py is?

Comment: So better to do with `virtualenv`.

Comment: Isn't it feasible with my windows pc? Why virtual environment required .. please let me know how to do it on my pc?

Comment: `python setup.py install` actually it's not generating `exe` it's installing packages only. `virtualenv` help to solve the desired folders nothing else.

Comment: Actually after running the `setup.py` I have seen an exe getting generated .. I am just thinking to get it created in my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issues when i was converting `.py` to `.exe` a while ago. eventually i managed to get `py2exe` to work using this as my `setup.py` file.

```
#command in cmd for py2exe
#1)get to directory
#2)enter "python setup.py py2exe"

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 2, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "myProject.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what i am looking for. I want that the exe getting created in the script folder should get created in my project folder thats it